# Robotframework import own Python library

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to create a Python library and then import it to robotframework. My Python library structure is:

```
autotestlibrary
|_ testkeywordlibrary
  |_ logintest.py
  |_ homepagetest.py
|_ testobject
  |_ loginpage.py
  |_ homepage.py
```

I have created init file into each folder. But when I import autotestlibray into robotframework it can't find my library.

Comment: Is `autotestlibrary` directory in one of the directories specified in `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: yes, autotestlibrary is under folder c:\workspace, i add path c:\worksapce in PYTHONPATH

Comment: Interesting. What is the exception you get when you `import autotestlibrary`?

Comment: in RIDE it can't find this library

Comment: I think @zvone ment for you to run Python interactively and try the import.
You would probably get similar errors from Tools>RIDE Log output.
(the Library will fail to import and show in red color if there are Python errors in it)

Comment: i find the reason for this, robotframeowork only can read the keyword libaray. so if i want import test keyworlibrary, i should create a same name class in __init__.py file. Thanks all.

Comment: @Vivien Someone edited the question and messed up your intent with the library structure. I've fixed it, please see that it is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Give the absolute path like:

```
Library    /absolute/path/Library.py
```

Answer (score 1):

If autotestlibrary is in PYTHONPATH environment variable then use

```
Library    autotestlibrary.xyz
```

where xyz can be:

- logintest.py
- homepagetest.py
- loginpage.py
- homepage.py

I suggest you to always import the child most library, all the parent libraries will be imported automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If your library is a class then the filename needs to be exactly as the class name.

So if you have a class inside of logintest.py which is called Logintest then your file needs to be renamed to Logintest.py

Read more here:
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#importing-libraries